# How to make content box slide automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider and the source code is in this URL [here](https://imageslidermaker.com/blog/make-your-image-slider-loop-using-jquery)

All works perfectly except for one thing: Is there a way I can get the slides going forward in case I do not click on the next button?

At the moment I have to click, to make it move to the next.

Here the running snippet

```js
$(function() {

  var ul = $(".slider ul");
  var slide_count = ul.children().length;
  var slide_width_pc = 100.0 / slide_count;
  var slide_index = 0;

  var first_slide = ul.find("li:first-child");
  var last_slide = ul.find("li:last-child");

  last_slide.clone().prependTo(ul);

  first_slide.clone().appendTo(ul);

  ul.find("li").each(function(indx) {
    var left_percent = (slide_width_pc * indx) + "%";
    $(this).css({"left":left_percent});
    $(this).css({width:(100 / slide_count) + "%"});
  });

  ul.css("margin-left", "-100%");

  $(".slider .prev").click(function() {
    slide(slide_index - 1);
  });

  $(".slider .next").click(function() {
    slide(slide_index + 1);
  });

  function slide(new_slide_index) {

    var margin_left_pc = (new_slide_index * (-100) - 100) + "%";

    ul.animate({"margin-left": margin_left_pc}, 400, function() {
      if(new_slide_index < 0) {
        ul.css("margin-left", ((slide_count) * (-100)) + "%");
        new_slide_index = slide_count - 1;
      }
      else if(new_slide_index >= slide_count) {
        ul.css("margin-left", "-100%");
        new_slide_index = 0;
      }
      slide_index = new_slide_index
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 550px;
  position: relative;
}
#main-navigation .container{
 max-width: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.slider ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.slider li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 33.333333%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: none;
}

.slider li img {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.slider button {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider button.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.slider button.next {
  right: 0;
}

.slider button:hover, .slider button:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.slider .content {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.slider .content a {
  color: inherit;
}

.first{
 background: url('/images/thermometer.jpg');
 background-position: 50%;
 background-size: cover;
}

.second{
 background: url('/images/green-bottles.jpg');
 background-position: 50%;
 background-size: cover;
}
.third{
 background: url('/images/green-bottles.jpg');
 background-position: 50%;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script><div class="containeeeer">
    <div class="slider">
        <ul>
            <li class="first flex">
                <div class="box-slider max-width flex align-center">
                <div>          <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.</p>
                <a href="#">Call to action</a>
                </div>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="second flex">

            </li>
            <li class="third flex">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="prev"><</button>
        <button class="next">></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `setTimeout()` function to automatically execute script after some delay:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    slide(slide_index + 1); // or slide_index - 1 in case of sliding back
}, 1000) // delay in ms
```

Make sure that you are clearing `timeout` with `clearTimeout(timeout)` when you are manually clicking buttons :)

More information about [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and (if you are interested in) [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: Mind sending a working snippet? I know I still need to work more on my javascript
will appreciate that

Comment: @deSousa I just edited your post with working example)

Comment: Really appreciate the support.

Comment: Only thing remaining is to set the height automatically according to the screen size

Comment: I have no idea about this. But I am currently testing the slider and noticed that after a while, the slider works automatically and suuuper fast. Have no idea what this can possibly be

Comment: @Limbo: I have rolled back your edit to the question, as it should not have been approved. Questions must be left in a "question state", so that answers given still make sense. If a question with non-working code is amended so the code works, it does not make sense for future readers who may wish to learn from it (and from any answers given).

Comment: @halfer seems like you're right (it was so long time ago, I even forgot that I edited this question :D) Thank you and sorry)